# Bibliotecas do Media Player Classic no meu projeto Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que irá funcionar como um tocador, porem os videos inseridos em meu software serão de vários formatos diferentes avi, mp4, flv e etc... por esse motivo eu não quero utilizar o windows media player, gostaria de algo mais completo como media player classic, existem bibliotecas dele? ou parecidas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia usar um [FFmpeg Wrapper](http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/) para converter vídeos para algum formato suportado pelo Windows Media Player a seu critério ou tentar algo com o VlcDotNet, já que ele também trabalha junto com o FFmpeg.

Ao meu ver, outra solução muito interessante seria **embutir o VLC Media Player** ao seu projeto:

- Você pode baixar a versão 1.1.9 do VLC (vlc-1.1.9-win32.exe) [aqui](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/1.1.9/win32/).

  Obs: Recomendo o uso da versão acima pois versões posteriores apresentaram alguns erros de incompatibilidade com projetos .NET, resultando na falha de criação do componente 'AxHost' e na própria `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.
- Adicione o COM component (axvlc.dll) ao registro usando o regsvr32. Para fazer isso, digite regsvr32 "CaminhoDeInstalacao\axvlc.dll" no prompt de comando, como no exemplo:

  `regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll"`
- Clique com o botão direito em sua ToolBox e clique em "Choose Items". Vá à aba "COM Components" e marque o VLC ActiveX Plugin v2.
- Adicione o componente ao seu formulário.

Agora, para escolher um vídeo e adicioná-lo à playlist você pode usar o [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Filter = "AVI (*.avi)|*.avi|MP4|*.mp4"; //Definindo o filtro (extensões dos vídeos pelos quais o OpenFileDialog buscará).

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Teste para verificar se o arquivo foi selecionado.
{
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(ofd.FileName, ofd.SafeFileName, null); //Adicionando vídeo à playlist.
    //Obs: a propriedade SafeFileName retornará o nome e a extensão do arquivo em questão.
}
```

Para **tocar**, **pausar/reproduzir** e **parar** basta usar os seguintes comandos:

```
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();

axVLCPlugin21.playlist.togglePause();

axVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop();
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vlc.DotNet/

Você chegou a tentar?

Comment: Olá @Guilherme Obrigado pela resposta. Fiz exatamente como você indicou em sua resposta porem quando executo meu form aparece varias mensagens de erro falando que não foi possível encontrar as dll da pasta plugin http://imageshack.com/a/img823/2790/39wq.jpg

Comment: Essa liba52tofloat32_plugin.dll consta na sua pasta plugins?

Comment: sim ela consta, ele mostra essa mensagens para todas as dll da pasta plugin. minha maquina é x64 projeto WP esta rodando como x64 e o VLC é x86, será que esse é problema ?

Comment: Acredito que seja esse o problema. Tente baixar uma dll para x64 ou acessar as propriedades do seu projeto (aba Build) para mudar a plataforma.

Comment: Erá isso mesmo selecionei a opção "Any CPU" e funcionou vou fazer os testes, por enquanto muito Obrigado.

Comment: @Guilherme o controle Activex funcionou perfeitamente estou conseguindo reproduzir videos e etc. porem eu preciso pegar dados como a duração do vídeo e a posição, mas os eventos do AxVLCPlugin2 parece não funcionar. postei essa pergunta agradeço caso possa me ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9576/activex-axvlcplugin2-nenhum-evento-funciona

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta à pergunta, espero ter ajudado (:

Answer (score 3):

Tuyoshi,

Tenho em mente agora algumas alternativas para você. As duas primeiras (MediaElement e WPF MediaKit) são específicas para WPF. As duas últimas (principalmente a última que estou tendendo a te dizer que é a melhor) funcionam no Windows Forms também.

**MediaElement**

Se você está considerando usar WPF e o componente nativo (MediaElement) para tocar media, tenha em mente que ele funciona muito bem caso você vá tocar apenas uma mídia. Com mais de uma mídia tocando, ou uma mídia 1080p em stretch para mais de um monitor, começa a causar stuttering.

Por baixo dos panos ele cria um ActiveX do Windows Media e decide entre DirectShow e Media Foundation. No caso de nenhum codec instalado, no windows 7 e 8, ele usará o codec nativo do windows (Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder).

**WPF MediaKit**

Esta é uma biblioteca opensource que, por baixo dos panos, também usa DirectShow e Media Foundation. Ela possui um elemento que substitui o MediaElement do WPF.

Parece ter uma implementação um pouco mais rápida e traz uma boa performance com dois monitores e vídeos 1080p. Com três monitores tocando três vídeos 1080p, passa a ter um pouco de stuttering dependendo da sua configuração de hardware/sistema.

**AxWindowsMediaPlayer**

O Windows Media Player pode ser instanciado via ActiveX e utilizado dentro da aplicação (funciona no Windows Forms também). Com três monitores, percebi muita perda de keyframes e com certeza foi a pior opção.

**DirectShow + MediaFoundation**

Essa, para mim, é a melhor solução. Você pode utilizar as bibliotecas DirectShow.Net e a MediaFoundation.Net.

Eles permitem que você aponte especificamente qual codec você quer usar. Se quiser ter uma noção de como construir sua aplicação em cima deles, dê uma olhada no GraphEdit ou GraphStudio, que é um software que monta o gráfico de filtros utilizados para renderizar um vídeo.

No final das contas, tudo vai depender de quanto o teu hardware aguenta e quais codecs você vai ter instalado. Lembrando que o windows já vem com um decoder de alguns tipos, tocando muitos mp4, avi e mpg out-of-the-box, mas não disponibiliza um demultiplexor para você usar, então você teria que, pelo menos, registrar um demux. Caso vá por esse caminho, dê uma olhada no mp4demux da GDCL.

(Desculpe não colocar os links para você, mas não tenho reputação o suficiente para isso)

Answer (score 2):

Creio que não tenha uma maneira simples de fazer isso em Windows Forms, sugiro que você use WPF, pois ele já tem componentes feitos especificamente para isso e que são bem simples de se trabalhar, além disso como você tem experiência com Windows Forms deve se acostumar rapidamente com ele.

Aqui tem um tutorial de como criar um player de música e vídeo com wpf.
(não se assuste com o xaml, a interface de criação é bem visual)
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/how-to-creating-a-complete-audio-video-player/

Comment: Rodrigo Santos o meu maior problema tem sido os variados formatos de mídia, em relação aos codecs como uma aplicação em WPF me ajudaria?