# Activex AxVLCPlugin2 nenhum evento funciona

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Possuo em meu form um **VLC Player**. Nele, eu preciso obter informações básicas como duração do vídeo e da posição atual. mas nenhum evento funciona.

Estou fazendo algo errado? Segue código:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    vlc.play += vlc_play;

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "AVI (*.avi)|*.avi|MP4|*.mp4"; //Definindo o filtro (extensões dos vídeos pelos quais o OpenFileDialog buscará).
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Teste para verificar se o arquivo foi selecionado.
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);
        vlc.playlist.items.clear();
        vlc.playlist.add(new Uri(ofd.FileName).AbsoluteUri); //Adicionando vídeo à playlist.
        vlc.playlist.play();
    }


}

void vlc_play(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(vlc.input.Position));
}
```

minha solução, infelizmente, é usar um timer para obter as informações.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer na parte do timer. Você só consegue obter as informações do video algum tempo após o play?

Comment: O evento Play ou o MediaPlayerPlaying não funcionam, na verdade nenhum evento funciona, não sei oque estou fazendo de errado. eu estou utilizando o objeto Timer com interval de 1 segundo pra pegar a posição atual porque o evento MediaPlayerPositionChanged não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

O mais interessante nesse caso seria usar o próprio evento MediaPlayerPositionChanged para obter a posição atual.

No caso, basta atribuir o *event handler*

```
vlc.MediaPlayerPositionChanged += vlc_play;
```

E trocar o parâmetro do mesmo, já que a classe [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) não consta na definição do próprio *delegate* a que ele se refere:

```
void vlc_play(object sender, AxAXVLC.DVLCEvents_MediaPlayerPositionChangedEvent e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(axVLCPlugin21.input.Position));
}
```

Comment: Eu já tentei isso mas simplesmente não funciona,  nenhum evento funciona.

Comment: Estranho, aqui está funcionando normalmente... Você não trocou o vlc.input.Position por e.Position? Porque nesse caso ele sempre vai indicar 0.

Comment: Não na verdade ele nem está entrando no método do evento, talvez seja a versão do activex eu estou usando a última versão e você?

Comment: Estou usando a 1.1.9 do VLC. Então só pode ser isso mesmo, experimente trocar por uma versão anterior do ActiveX.